# html tag within javascript variable parse(parse <p> tag)

Tags: javascript, html

```
var str2 = "<p>Apple apple ball</p>";
document.querySelector('textarea[placeholder="description"]').value = str2;
```

How parse the paragraph tag, is it possible?

Comment: what do you want to parse from it?

Comment: Have you checked what `<textarea><p>Apple apple ball</p></textarea>` directly inserted into the HTML would result in in your browser? If so, why would you expect anything to be different if the value was set via JS, instead of being present as the initial textarea content already?

Comment: I have to enter three set of paragraphes, without <p> tag, paragraph are merged

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - but if you want to get the text inside the P tag using javascript: use a regex match of /<p>(.*?)<\/p>/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the variable is a string, even with the paragraph tag included.

So you'd first you could create an element to then get the value of it by adding the string to it as html:

```
var str2 = "<p>Apple apple ball</p>";
var tempElem = document.createElement('div');
tempElem.innerHTML = str2;
console.log(tempElem.innerText);
```

Then you can get the value of the `tempElem` through `innerText`.